# IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have just changed framework of my project from 2.0 to 4.0 and I am getting error while opening URL Rewrite pages. I have many things but none of them working.

Please help me regarding this.
**Error :**

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

**Web.config:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="8.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <remove name="Plesk. SEO-safe redirect for http://www.theprojectjugaad.com" />
        <rule name="Plesk. SEO-safe redirect for http://www.theprojectjugaad.com" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.theprojectjugaad.com" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
          </conditions>
          <serverVariables />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://theprojectjugaad.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What URL (exactly) are you accessing, and what rewrite are you expecting to happen with it for the application to work?

Comment: I have used Global.asax for URL rewriting. I am trying to access : http://www.theprojectjugaad.com/Login/Login.html , If I am using .aspx then It is working fine.

Comment: I have no idea what your file structure looks like, but your rewrite rule has `enabled="false"` set so if it worked before, the rewrite is probably not the problem.

Comment: yes, It was working fine.

Comment: The IIS error page is saying that it's apparently looking in `D:\Inetpub\vhosts\jeetenparmar.net\theprojectjugaad.com\Login\Login.html` for Login.html, but not finding it. Where is that file _actually_ located?

Comment: It is hosted on shared server, and jeetenparmar.net is main domain.

Comment: Yes, but where in the file system is `Login.html` actually stored?

Comment: it is not Login.html page, page name is something else. It is stored in theprojectjugaad.com

Answer (score 0):

is this been resolved?

I had similar error and was resolved by removing WebDAV from system.webServer

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```